# How to use functions with ngOptions?

Tags: angularjs

I have these 2 functions,

```
function functionCall(orderByRelease_date){
  orderByClick = "release_date"
  orderBy();
  console.log ('release')
}

function functionCall(orderByCreated_at){
  orderByClick = "created_at"
  orderBy();
  console.log ('created')
}
```

These functions set a variable `orderByClick` for this function,

```
var orderBy = function(){
  $scope.movies = response.data;
  var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
  $scope.orderedMovies = orderBy($scope.movies, orderByClick);

  var movies = $scope.orderedMovies
  var i,j,temparray,chunk = 8, movieGroups=[];
  for (i=0,j=movies.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
      temparray = movies.slice(i,i+chunk);
      movieGroups.push(temparray);
  }
  $scope.movieGroupsSuggestions = movieGroups
}
```

I had created a options list like this,

```
%select
  %option{:onselect => "functionCall(orderByRelease_date)"} Sort by release date.
  %option{:onselect => "functionCall(orderByCreated_at)"} Sort by newest
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

So I stumbled on to ngoptions and it seemed the way to go, but it's not clear to me how I can use functions with it.

I've created a scope with the options,

```
$scope.orderList = [
  'created_at',
  'release_date'
]
```

And a ng-options element,

```
%select{"ng-options" => "option for option in orderList"}
```

This displays the values from orderList, but how do I hook this up so that the variable `oderByClick` in my `orderBy` function changes?

Comment: y dont u use ng-repeat with orderBy

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But I'm using js code (the orderBy function) to create rows with movie objects in them. So the ng-repeat doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add the `ng-model` directive to your select element.

Comment: @georgeawg and then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question,

I've created a scope with the values I want to insert in my javascript code,

```
$scope.listOfOptions = [
  'release_date',
  'created_at',
];
```

Then create a function that reacts to the ng-options,

```
$scope.selectedItemChanged = function(){
  orderByClick = $scope.selectedItem;
  orderBy();
}
```

So this sets the value from listOfOptions to the variable orderByClick, and then calls orderBy function.

And then in the oderBy function I have,

```
$scope.orderedMovies = orderBy($scope.movies, orderByClick);
```

And this is the haml,

```
%select{"ng-change" => "selectedItemChanged()", "ng-model" => "selectedItem", "ng-options" => "option for option in listOfOptions"}
```

My problem was not knowing about the `ng-change`, that's what creates the interaction between controller and the view.